# Reactions buttons under post published by telegram bot

Tags: bots, telegram, telebot

I am created a telegram bot which send my post to the particular channel.
And I wonder how can I make it add something like like and dislike buttons under post and a counter for every reaction.

*I know how to create this buttons:*

[image]

**But how to make *this* not using other bots?**
[image]

Thank You for any help in advance.